# Laravel query Builder - Union - Column not found Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, union

I'm using **Laravel** Query builder to generate a union query. and one of my query in the union have an 3 select fields , other query in union have 2 select fields . so i added an empty fields to match the number of column. the laravel says the following **error**

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'field list'

```
$i = 0;
foreach($sources as $key=>$value)
{   
 $db = $value['db'];
 $table = $value['table'] ;
 $fields = $value['fields'];

  $join = DB::table($db.'.'.$table)
          ->whereIn($table.'.'.$table.'_sys_id',$value['values'])
          ->select($fields);

if($i <1)
{
$tagResultQuery = $join;

}
else{
$tagResultQuery->union($join);
}

$i++;
}

$result = $tagResultQuery->get();
```

Comment: Please show us the actual code.

Comment: Where is the query?

Comment: Yes please show us the code part here, However you might put the column name as `select ' '`, where you should use `select ' ' as <same_col_name>` to make a empty column in the selected list.

Comment: Hi i have updated the code.

Comment: I hope the as <some coloum name > will work. but in the above code how can i add this ?

Comment: Thank you @AvishekChat , I managed to fixed it using your advise. its fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Because the names of your columns are different.Here is an example

```
SELCT 
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
FROM tbl_1
UNION
SELCT 
    col1,
    col2,
    '' as col3
FROM tbl_2
```

if you do not add ('' as col3) will be error like yours

Answer (score 0):

You should put all possible column to make the **fields** array.

```
 $fileds_array= $value['fields'];
 $fields=[
    'colA'=>if(isset($fileds_array['colA'])) ? $fileds_array['colA'] : '',
    'colA'=>if(isset($fileds_array['colB'])) ? $fileds_array['colB'] : '',
    ........................
    ........................
    'colN'=>if(isset($fileds_array['colN'])) ? $fileds_array['colN'] : ''
];
```

This should works.

Comment: Hi actually the $values['fields'] is an array. do you this this will work ?

Comment: ohoo..sorry..then you have to parse the array ..I will do the modification in sometime.

Comment: I think you should try this once..@Vigikaran

Comment: Please find my solution in my answer. this will help you sometime. its very easy method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I managed to fixed by replace the Select statement with the following

```
->select(
   $fields[0].' AS tag_title',
   $fields[0].' AS tag_url',
   $fields[0].' AS tag_unique_name'
  )
```